# Pc freezes then wont boot. The fans spin, but HDD activity light is off

Tags: boot

I'm having a problem with my PC and this isn't the first time it's happened. 
For a few days now, when I turned my PC on, it didn't immediately start to boot up. The monitor said "No signal" and the machine just sat there although the power light was on and the fans were running. Then, after a few minutes, it would begin to boot as if nothing was wrong. Today I started my machine and it ran ok for about 10 minutes. Then the whole thing froze up and I had to shut it down and restart by holding the power button. When it rebooted, the same thing happened again and again and now finally it wont boot up at all. 
This happened before about 8 months ago. I ended up taking it to the shop after getting a blue screen. They replaced the HDD and upgraded it to windows 7 and it has worked fine since then. However, they charged an arm and a leg for the work and I dont want to have to go back there again. As this is a recurring fault I figure its a mechanical problem of some sort but I'm not sure what.
Any ideas?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sounds like a hardware problem, but could be real tricky to diagnose.  You may have to remove/replace each component in turn, seeing if it resolves the problem. On the other hand, simply vacuuming any dust out of your heat sinks and reseating things may sort it out.

Comment: Yep. It seems like the "actual" problem is the Hard Drive. However, there must be something that is causing the Hard Drive to die. I would try cleaning the dust and making sure everything is attached correctly. (Perhaps it's time to get a new computer) ;)

Comment: Can you list your system specs for me, just checking a few things.

Comment: @AceLegend - if it were the hard drive,wouldn't there be a message othe screen that no boot device found after POST?

Comment: Does the computer power up at all now? Does it seem to hang at POST (no bios splash screen) with the monitor still saying no signal?

Comment: Your right. It should still boot through the motherboard's firmware. It might be the motherboard that's the problem. Perhaps its fried.

Comment: Actually. If something is wrong with the motherboard then it will never get to the hard drive. That might be why the hard drive light never comes on.

Comment: With what is supplied thus far, it sounds more likee culprate is PSU. A fairly inexpensive item that can cause frusation in troubleshooting.

Answer (score 2):

I tried reseating all the power and data cables I could reach and blew some dust out of it and it seems to be running smoothly now. I guess one of the connectors was a little loose. 
Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: I was about to suggest that this sounded like a loose connection somewhere. You might also want to remove and re-seat all the expansion cards (if any) that you have installed. You should be able to use *light* pressue with a soft (new!) "children's" toothbrush as well as gently blowing at the sockets to clear out any dust or residue that might have accumulated and could be preventing good electrical contact. Just be careful not to spit at the motherboard! :)

Comment: They make special vacuum cleaner attachments for cleaning out computers, plus you can buy "canned air" for blowing out dust.